# Can I get the inner html of an element before interpolation in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to get the original html of a HTMLElement before Angular does any property binding or interpolation. If possible I would also have the option to replace the text by another (with the same variables). I want to use the original text as a key to provide translations.

For instance if I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>Color: {{ color }}</div>',
})
export class AppComponent  {
  color = 'blue';
}
```

I would like to get `Color: {{ color }}` instead of `Color: blue`.

The reason is that we are currently having a hybrid app with old translation files that would look like this (eg. a UK version):

```
msgid "Color: {{ color }}"
msgstr "Colour: {{ color }}"
```

So it needs the original string since that's used as the key. So I just created a simple service that passes the information along to the old upgraded service so we can keep using the old translation files for now.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?why you want to do this ?

Comment: Edited the original with some more information

Comment: angular build will replace all html template it you look to angular build result so the best case you can use id ,or class name ?

Comment: you mean create a new key for the translation files based on a unique property such as id or classname?